# package Push Item Method Encodes attribute values

Tags: web8, templating, tbb

I was trying to push content from C# Fragment  using  below snippet

```cs
Item componentItem = package.GetByType(ContentType.Component);
Component component= engine.GetObject(componentItem.GetAsSource().GetValue("ID")) as Component;
ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);
TextField text = fields["text"] as TextField;
string description = text.Value;
log.Info("Before Push:"+description);
package.PushItem("Output", package.CreateHtmlItem(description));
```

On Debugging:

CSharpSourceTemplate: Before Push:

```html
<a href="&amp;=" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">&amp;Check</a>
<strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Check</strong>
```

CSharpSourceTemplate: Output:

```html
<a href="&" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">&amp;Check</a>
<strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Check</strong>
```

I have tried all different content type in `package.CreateStringItem` method, but attribute value is encoding from `&amp;` to `&`

Due to this encoding my XML is breaking, have any faced this issue earlier?

Comment: I'm confused. Bart's answer says he can't reproduce your problem and you accepted the answer. Did you figure out what the problem was? If so, please expain.

Comment: removed all other TBB's and verified the output parameter as bart did ... there are another bunch of compound templates other than default action which might cause decoding. Verifying exactly which TBB encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly when using `Package.CreateHtmlItem(htmlContent)` (which is similar to using `Package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Html, htmlContent)`) then your content will be automatically HTML encoded.

So I would recommend using `Package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, htmlContent)` instead if the automatic HTML encoding is in your way. But be aware that if you use the `Default Finish Actions` TBB in your Compound Template, there is a `Convert XML to HTML` TBB at the end there which tries to convert the XML of the package item called Output into HTML. This also does some encoding which might be unwanted, and you might need to remove it from the TBB pipeline.

## Update

I tried using the following code in a C# TBB in SDL Web 8.5

```
string description = "<a href=\"&amp;\">&amp;Check</a>";
package.PushItem("HtmlOutput", package.CreateHtmlItem(description));
package.PushItem("Html2Output", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Html, description));
package.PushItem("TextOutput", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, description));
```

And the outcome in the Template Builder is:

**HtmlOutput**

```
<a href="&amp;">&amp;Check</a>
```

**Html2Output**

```
<a href="&amp;">&amp;Check</a>
```

**TextOutput**

```
<a href="&amp;">&amp;Check</a>
```

So other than a dfference in the type of the package items (`text/html` or `text/plain`), I don't see any HTML encoding happening at all actually.

Which makes me think that maybe you need to check the line `TextField text = fields["text"] as TextField;` and validate that this field is in fact a `TextField` and not an `XhtmlField` (a.k.a. Format Area).

## Update 2

Web 8 shows me exactly the same as Web 8.5, see the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Hi Bart, Thanks for Reply... Yes I tried using `Package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, htmlContent)`, but  in Template Builder I can see Output parameter is still in encoded format.

Comment: @Kumar_diru as mentioned, it is important at what step you look at the Output parameter, maybe you can **edit** your question and supply a few more details about the Template and if the `Output` is taken directly after executing your C# Fragment or if it is at the end of the line.

Comment: Hi Bart, I consume parameter directly after executing C# Fragment

Comment: @Kumar_diru see my updated answer, I don't see this happening in SDL Web 8.5

Comment: Hi bart. Thanks for updates. current version of Mine was Web 8 . In my question if we observe `Before Push` log  has encoded value but upon push it got decoded.